# Questions "just for curiosity"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is it acceptable to ask questions "just for curiosity", or should we refrain from that to avoid overloading the site already choked with panicked questions? Also, if we do, should we somehow mark it as "low-priority" in some way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A good question is a good question, as long as it follows the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) you should be fine, some of our best questions are people wondering why something works.

Comment: Still, should we show that the question is not such high priority in any way to avoid choking the site?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, the site is running fine.